# Find the eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix by only using linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> For any stochastic matrix, there will always be an eigenvalue "one".

The way I prove is that if A is a stochastic matrix, then the sum of any of its columns will be exactly one. Then take the transpose of this matrix to be $A^T$. Then, the sum of any row of $A^T$ will be one. Thus, in particular, $A^T$ times a column vector that only has one will be the vector itself times one(since the sum of a row of $A^T$ is one). As a result,$A^T$ must have an eigenvalue $1$ with an eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ \vdots \\1 \end{pmatrix}$

Thus det$(A^T-I)=0$. And since transpose won't change determinant, det$(A-I)=0$. Hence A has eigenvalue one.

However, first I'm not sure whether this proof is valid. Also, I want to ask that is there a way to prove the existence of eigenvalue one for stochastic matrix A just by using linear operation $(A-I)$ (specifically use the properties like null space, range...)? The way I want to approach this is by trying to prove $(A-I)$ is not injective or $(A-I)$ is not subjective.

My first idea is try to prove $(A-I)$ is not subjective i.e. dim range $(A-I)\leq $ $dim V$. Then I also found that range $(A-I)$ is invariant under linear operator A. Then I found I'm stuck. Any helps? Thanks.

Comment: Let $X$ the vector you mentioned containing only $1$. What is $\left(A-I\right)X$ ?

Comment: In fact, the reason I use the transpose matrix is to deal with the situation $(A-I)X$ since I don't know what this should be. All I know $(A-I)X$ means $\begin{pmatrix} *-1\\ \vdots \\* \end{pmatrix}$ +...+$\begin{pmatrix} *\\ \vdots \\ *-1\end{pmatrix}$ and each column sum together will give zero

Comment: You can still deal with the $^{t}A$ as they have the same spectrum. So if you can prove $\left(^{t}A-I\right)X=0$ then you know $X$ is in the kernel of $A-I$ hence it is not injective.

Comment: @Atmos: same spectrum does not mean same eigenvectors. And "same spectra" needs a proof which is the goal of the question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The image of $A-I$ consists of vectors whose sum of coordinates is $0$. Indeed, if $v$ is any vector, then the first coordinate of $(A-I)v$ is $\langle r_1(A), v\rangle -v_1$ (dot product of the first row of $A$ and $v$ minus the first coordinate of $v$, the second coordinate is
$\langle r_2(A), v\rangle -v_2$,..., the $n$-th coordinate is
$\langle r_n(A), v\rangle -v_n$. Then the sum of coordinates is $\langle \sum r_i(A), v\rangle -\sum v_i=0$.

Thus $A-I$ is not surjective, as you wanted.